# When exactly does an Activity reach a CREATED state?

Tags: android

I am asking this because of the confusion about the created state:

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#oncreate) on `onCreate()`:

*You must implement this callback, which fires when the system first creates the activity. On activity creation, the activity enters the Created state. In the onCreate() method, you perform basic application startup logic that should happen only once for the entire life of the activity.*

It raises following questions:

- Does the CREATED state occur before or after the call to onCreate()?
- Is the CREATED state constant used below different from the theoretical meaning of state being defined in the above excerpt, i.e, I should just read this and move on not focusing on the created state phrase?

Before you answer, there is the Lifecycle.State class from Lifecycle Aware components where in you can see the meaning of various states as follows:

```
     /**
     * Lifecycle states. You can consider the states as the nodes in a graph and
     * {@link Event}s as the edges between these nodes.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public enum State {
        /**
         * Destroyed state for a LifecycleOwner. After this event, this Lifecycle will not dispatch
         * any more events. For instance, for an {@link android.app.Activity}, this state is reached
         * <b>right before</b> Activity's {@link android.app.Activity#onDestroy() onDestroy} call.
         */
        DESTROYED,

        /**
         * Initialized state for a LifecycleOwner. For an {@link android.app.Activity}, this is
         * the state when it is constructed but has not received
         * {@link android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle) onCreate} yet.
         */
        INITIALIZED,

        /**
         * Created state for a LifecycleOwner. For an {@link android.app.Activity}, this state
         * is reached in two cases:
         * <ul>
         *     <li>after {@link android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle) onCreate} call;
         *     <li><b>right before</b> {@link android.app.Activity#onStop() onStop} call.
         * </ul>
         */
        CREATED,

        /**
         * Started state for a LifecycleOwner. For an {@link android.app.Activity}, this state
         * is reached in two cases:
         * <ul>
         *     <li>after {@link android.app.Activity#onStart() onStart} call;
         *     <li><b>right before</b> {@link android.app.Activity#onPause() onPause} call.
         * </ul>
         */
        STARTED,

        /**
         * Resumed state for a LifecycleOwner. For an {@link android.app.Activity}, this state
         * is reached after {@link android.app.Activity#onResume() onResume} is called.
         */
        RESUMED;

        /**
         * Compares if this State is greater or equal to the given {@code state}.
         *
         * @param state State to compare with
         * @return true if this State is greater or equal to the given {@code state}
         */
        public boolean isAtLeast(@NonNull State state) {
            return compareTo(state) >= 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would like to believe the `CREATED` state occurs after the call to `onCreate()` because `CREATED` implies that at that moment it already has been created while `onCreate()` as from the name implies it is under creation for now and the comment in the `Lifecycle.State` class implies the same for `CREATED` state

Comment: Seems the description in the `Lifecycle.State` class is pretty clear about this. My question: Why do you care? Is this just an "I'm curious" question or is there a reason you need to know this?

Comment: @DavidWasser They use this language everywhere as in, the Activity has reached the created state now. I want to be clear of what they mean every time as well as now the lifecycle components define the same properly so more so the reason to have a clear understanding of the same

Answer (score 2):

I would like to believe the `CREATED` state occurs after the call to `onCreate()` because CREATED implies that at that moment it already has been created while `onCreate()` as from the name implies it is under creation for now and the comment in the Lifecycle.State class implies the same for `CREATED` state.

So to conclude:

`onCreate()` -> Under the process of creation

`CREATED` -> Already has finished the process of creation

The comment from LifeCycle state implies same as said

```kotlin
 /**
         * Created state for a LifecycleOwner. For an {@link android.app.Activity}, this state
         * is reached in two cases:
         * <ul>
         *     <li>after {@link android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle) onCreate} call;
         *     <li><b>right before</b> {@link android.app.Activity#onStop() onStop} call.
         * </ul>
```

Comment: Upvoted as this is sensible. But will wait to see other responses as well. Thanks.